# how do I design my own filter in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Can I design my very own filter for removing noise in images in MATLAB by changing the kernel / mask values . I am new to MATLAB and I really need help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.  The [`filter2`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/filter2.html) function takes a user-specified filter kernel.  So to apply, for example, a vertical Sobel filter:

```
h = [ 1  2  1 
      0  0  0
     -1 -2 -1 ];

im_out = filter2(h, im_in);
```

If you're asking how to choose the values for your filter kernel, well, that's a vast topic.  But if you have the Image Processing Toolbox, then you could use the [`fspecial`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/images/ref/fspecial.html) function to get several pre-defined kernels.

Comment: hey this is the kernel right that was developed how do i apply it to my image?

Comment: i am getting the following error please help

im_in = imread('Canada_landscape1.jpg');
subplot(2,2,1),imshow(im_in)
h = [ 1  2  1 
      0  0  0
     -1 -2 -1 ];

im_out = filter2(im_in, h);
im1= filter2(im_in,im_out,'sober');

subplot(2,2,2),imshow(im1)
Error in ==> project at 8
im_out = filter2(im_in, h);
 


??? Error using ==> rot90 at 22
A must be a 2-D matrix.

Error in ==> filter2 at 41
stencil = rot90(b,2);

Error in ==> project at 8
im_out = filter2(im_in, h);

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is all you need to get started.
Then if you want to learn more, these helped me immensely at the beginning:

For concepts
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/fourier/
Code not in Matlab but this is one of the best tutorials I have seen

For Matlab check
http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/category/image-deblurring/ 
and
http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/category/fourier-transforms/

Answer (score -1):

You can review all the existing filters and propose changes in them. A thorough analysis would be beneficial in that case.

There are different filters for removing impulse noise, gaussian noise etc.

You can start of with finding the noise present in images and go step by step in counteracting the problem

The MATLAB help section provides a lot of links for the same.